# Angular material dialog emitter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have the following example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-dialog-so-3z9big

May I ask you, why is the `EventEmitter` `delete` not emitted when called in subscribe?

Comment: please consider adding at least some content from the link to your post so your post won't become useless in case the url changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're wondering why `console.log('confirm action');` is not logged to the console.

Your output of the `TestComponent` is called `@Output() delete`.

In your AppComponent you reference `(confirm)`:

```
<test (confirm)="onConfirm()"></test>
```

Change that to `delete`:

```
<test (delete)="onConfirm()"></test>
```